Define a closure in struct and then use a value from the struct to calculate the return in the implementation
It appears in zig we are able to define function types as properties of structs. I am wondering how to use struct values to create the function response.
In the following code:
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    const t = Animal{
        .name = "My Name",
        .age = 5,
        .talk = *const fn () [_]u8 {return .{.name}},
        .doubleAge = *const fn () i32 {return 2 * .{.age}},
    };

    std.log.info("{s}", .{t.talk()});
    std.log.info("{}", .{t.doubleAge()});
}

const Animal = struct {
    name: []u8,
    age: i32,
    talk: fn () []u8,
    doubleAge: fn () i32,
};

The .talk function has a compiler error for "not being able to determine array size"
The .doubleAge function has a compiler error for "not being able to instantiate array"

Zig does not have closures. If you want to access the struct, you will need to pass it as a parameter to the function:
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    const t = Animal{
        .age = 5,
        .doubleAge = doubleAge,
        // or you can use some other approach to declare the function locally,
        // for example:
        // .doubleAge = (struct {
        //  fn _(self: Animal) i32 {
        //      return 2 * self.age;
        //  }
        // })._,
    };
    std.log.info("{}", .{ t.doubleAge(t) }); // prints: 10
}

const Animal = struct {
    age: i32,
    doubleAge: fn (Animal) i32,
};

fn doubleAge(self: Animal) i32 {
    return 2 * self.age;
}

Note, that these aren't function pointers, but function bodies, which only exist at compile time. If you do std.log.info("{}", .{ @sizeOf(Animal) });, it will print 4 (for a single i32). As I understand it, this only creates an association between a particular function and an instance of the struct at compile time:
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    const foo = Animal{
        .age = 1,
        .doubleAge = (struct {
            fn _(self: Animal) i32 {
                return 2 * self.age;
            }
        })._,
    };
    const bar = Animal{
        .age = 1,
        .doubleAge = (struct {
            fn _(self: Animal) i32 {
                // actually triple
                return 3 * self.age;
            }
        })._,
    };
    std.log.info("{}", .{ foo.doubleAge(foo) }); // prints: 2
    std.log.info("{}", .{ bar.doubleAge(bar) }); // prints: 3
    std.log.info("{}", .{ foo.doubleAge(bar) }); // prints: 2
    std.log.info("{}", .{ bar.doubleAge(foo) }); // prints: 3
}

const Animal = struct {
    age: i32,
    doubleAge: fn (Animal) i32,
};


.name = "My Name",
.talk = *const fn () [_]u8 {return .{.name}},
.doubleAge = *const fn () i32 {return 2 * .{.age}},


This syntax is completely wrong:

String literals are immutable/const in Zig, but you declared name as a slice of mutable bytes. This won't compile.
A function cannot be declared like this, it has to be in a struct (a file is a struct too).
In the struct you declare a function body (fn () ...), but here you're trying to declare a function pointer (*const fn () ...).
In the struct you use a slice ([]u8), but here you're attempting to use array literal syntax ([_]u8).
.{.name} and .{.age} - make no sense.


If you make doubleAge *fn (Animal) i32, then the struct can exist and be passed around properly at runtime. Initialize it with .doubleAge = &doubleAge

@pfg *const fn (Animal) i32 - const is an important part of the declaration (at least in 0.13)

sorry I meant *const. definitely shouldn't use just fn as a type directly for a runtime struct, it will cause errors later.
